Usage of はどれだ + sentence understanding
確かに. しつこそうだな...なまじ詳しいから素人の会話にイラついてそうだし, 自分で言うにも適切な言葉はどれだ！って渋い顔しそう
The character in the novel I'm reading exclaims this over another's character personality.
He points out the character is indeed obstinate and because he's knowledgeable, when he deals with 素人の会話 he gets irritated. Then he also adds
" 自分で言うにも適切な言葉はどれだ！って渋い顔しそう"
I understand "って渋い顔しそう" is akin to "A bitter face that says..."
but I'm very stumbled on the meaning of
"自分で言うにも適切な言葉はどれだ！"
My vague reading would be akin to "自分で言うにも適切な言葉" the proper word to say something? But I'm honestly kinda puzzled here. Finally the character adds "はどれだ" which I asusme is どれ for "which"? Which are the proper word? However the sentence ends with どれだ instead of どれか I'm not sure I'm suppose to take as a question.
